# How can migrate buckets without losing the public permissions on objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I need migrate a couple of buckets between two AWS accounts. This can be possible with the AWS CLI doing a some configurations and a then copy from one S3 to the other. I followed [Copy S3 Objects From Another AWS Account](https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/) and it all worked fine. However, when I reviewed the permissions of the objects, the public access isn't enabled.

Some antecedents:

- My source bucket is private but can have public content
- My destination bucket have the same configuration of my source bucket
- Some files of my source bucket have public access enabled
- After migrate my content, the files in my destination bucket with
  access public enabled lose this permission

In this moment I need migrate the content to my destination bucket without losing the public access of my objects. I looked for this in the AWS documentation and in other blogs, but I didn't find anything.

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add public access permissions to your copied objects using the --acl param in your sync. From the url that you pasted in your question i am seeing that you used the generic command:

```
aws s3 sync s3://awsexamplesourcebucket s3://awsexampledestinationbucket
```

In the above command add the --acl param:

```
aws s3 sync s3://awsexamplesourcebucket s3://awsexampledestinationbucket --acl 'public-read'
```

--acl (string) Sets the ACL for the object when the command is performed. If you use this parameter you must have the "s3:PutObjectAcl" permission included in the list of actions for your IAM policy. Only accepts values of private, public-read, public-read-write, authenticated-read, aws-exec-read, bucket-owner-read, bucket-owner-full-control and log-delivery-write.

If some of your objects needs to be public and others not then you need to use the above command in combination with **[--include ]** and **[--exclude ]** in order to grant public access to some of your objects and private to others.

Reference

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html